# AICc results in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, feature-selection, aic

I used the model:

```
Model1 <- glm(disease ~ Distance_ue + Pop_density + Alt + Ave.temp + Ave.precip + 
                        Urban.Rural + (1| Sites), family=gaussian)
```

I then used the `dredge` function to obtain an AICc results table.

Model selection results for models predicting the effect of various predictor variables on `disease` (presence or absence) in birds in 10 research sites. `Site` was used as a random term. Predictor variables were classification of `Urban / Rural` (categorical - either labelled as urban or rural), `distance to the urban edge` (continuous), `population density` (continuous), `altitude` (continuous), `average temperature` (continuous) and `average precipitation` (continuous).

The issue I have is that in the results table there is no parameter estimate given for classification of urban or  rural which is the categorical variable - it only gives a $\pm$ sign (please see image below for the results table). Is this normal? Why is it doing this?

[image: AICc results table]

Comment: When you use a function not in the vanilla distribution of R, please state the package it's from. I presume you mean the `dredge` function in package `MuMin`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal and you need to use `coefficients(Model1)` like what I did in the example below to find the estimated parameters.

```
> require(MuMIn)
> counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
> outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
> treatment <- gl(3,3)
> glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment+outcome*treatment, family = poisson())
> d=dredge(glm.D93)
> print(d)
Global model call: glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment + outcome * treatment, 
    family = poisson())
---
Model selection table 
  (Int) otc trt otc:trt df logLik  AICc   delta  weight
8 2.890 +   +   +       9  -20.816 -120.4   0.00 1     
1 2.813                 1  -26.107   54.8 175.15 0     
2 3.045 +               3  -23.381   57.6 177.93 0     
3 2.813     +           3  -26.107   63.0 183.38 0     
4 3.045 +   +           5  -23.381   76.8 197.13 0     
> coefficients(d)
  (Intercept)    outcome2   outcome3   treatment2   treatment3 outcome2:treatment2 outcome3:treatment2 outcome2:treatment3 outcome3:treatment3
8    2.890372 -0.05715841 -0.1823216 1.053605e-01 3.285041e-01          -0.6359888           0.1823216          -0.5967681          -0.5516476
1    2.813411          NA         NA           NA           NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA
2    3.044522 -0.45425527 -0.2929871           NA           NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA
3    2.813411          NA         NA 8.933946e-14 1.006395e-12                  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA
4    3.044522 -0.45425527 -0.2929871 8.716884e-16 4.557335e-16                  NA                  NA                  NA                  NA
```

You can try `str` to see what else you can extract like below:

```
> str(d)
Classes ‘model.selection’ and 'data.frame':     5 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ (Intercept)      : num  2.89 2.81 3.04 2.81 3.04
     $ outcome          : Factor w/ 1 level "+": 1 NA 1 NA 1
 $ treatment        : Factor w/ 1 level "+": 1 NA NA 1 1
     $ outcome:treatment: Factor w/ 1 level "+": 1 NA NA NA NA
 $ df               : num  9 1 3 3 5
     $ logLik           : num  -20.8 -26.1 -23.4 -26.1 -23.4
 $ AICc             : num  -120.4 54.8 57.6 63 76.8
     $ delta            : num  0 175 178 183 197
 $ weight           : num  1.00 9.25e-39 2.31e-39 1.51e-40 1.56e-43
     - attr(*, "calls")=List of 5
      ..$ 8: language glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment + outcome:treatment + 1, family = poisson())
  ..$ 1: language glm(formula = counts ~ 1, family = poisson())
      ..$ 2: language glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + 1, family = poisson())
  ..$ 3: language glm(formula = counts ~ treatment + 1, family = poisson())
      ..$ 4: language glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment + 1, family = poisson())
 - attr(*, "global")=List of 30
  ..$ coefficients     : Named num  2.8904 -0.0572 -0.1823 0.1054 0.3285 ...
      .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "(Intercept)" "outcome2" "outcome3" "treatment2" ...
      ..$ residuals        : Named num  -7.89e-16 -6.27e-16 -4.74e-16 -7.11e-16 -1.07e-15 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ fitted.values    : Named num  18 17 15 20 10 ...
      .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
      ..$ effects          : Named num  -34.8891 1.7379 1.4563 -0.0294 -0.0219 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "(Intercept)" "outcome2" "outcome3" "treatment2" ...
  ..$ R                : num [1:9, 1:9] -12.2 0 0 0 0 ...
      .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. .. ..$ : chr  "(Intercept)" "outcome2" "outcome3" "treatment2" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "(Intercept)" "outcome2" "outcome3" "treatment2" ...
      ..$ rank             : int 9
  ..$ qr               :List of 5
      .. ..$ qr   : num [1:9, 1:9] -12.247 0.337 0.316 0.365 0.258 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
      .. .. .. ..$ : chr  "(Intercept)" "outcome2" "outcome3" "treatment2" ...
  .. ..$ rank : int 9
      .. ..$ qraux: num  1.35 1.61 1.52 1.54 1.2 ...
  .. ..$ pivot: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
      .. ..$ tol  : num 1e-11
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
  ..$ family           :List of 12
      .. ..$ family    : chr "poisson"
  .. ..$ link      : chr "log"
      .. ..$ linkfun   :function (mu)  
  .. ..$ linkinv   :function (eta)  
      .. ..$ variance  :function (mu)  
  .. ..$ dev.resids:function (y, mu, wt)  
      .. ..$ aic       :function (y, n, mu, wt, dev)  
  .. ..$ mu.eta    :function (eta)  
      .. ..$ initialize:  expression({     if (any(y < 0))          stop("negative values not allowed for the 'Poisson' family")     n <- rep.int(1, nobs)     mustart <- y + 0.1 })
  .. ..$ validmu   :function (mu)  
      .. ..$ valideta  :function (eta)  
  .. ..$ simulate  :function (object, nsim)  
      .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "family"
      ..$ linear.predictors: Named num  2.89 2.83 2.71 3 2.3 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ deviance         : num 3.77e-15
      ..$ aic              : num 59.6
  ..$ null.deviance    : num 10.6
      ..$ iter             : int 3
  ..$ weights          : Named num  18 17 15 20 10 ...
      .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
      ..$ prior.weights    : Named num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ df.residual      : int 0
      ..$ df.null          : int 8
  ..$ y                : Named num  18 17 15 20 10 20 25 13 12
      .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
      ..$ converged        : logi TRUE
  ..$ boundary         : logi FALSE
      ..$ model            :'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ counts   : num  18 17 15 20 10 20 25 13 12
      .. ..$ outcome  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
  .. ..$ treatment: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
      .. ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula' length 3 counts ~ outcome + treatment + outcome * treatment
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(counts, outcome, treatment)
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:3] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
      .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "counts" "outcome" "treatment"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "outcome" "treatment" "outcome:treatment"
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:3] "outcome" "treatment" "outcome:treatment"
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:3] 1 1 2
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(counts, outcome, treatment)
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:3] "numeric" "factor" "factor"
      .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "counts" "outcome" "treatment"
      ..$ call             : language glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment + outcome * treatment, family = poisson())
  ..$ formula          :Class 'formula' length 3 counts ~ outcome + treatment + outcome * treatment
      .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
      ..$ terms            :Classes 'terms', 'formula' length 3 counts ~ outcome + treatment + outcome * treatment
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(counts, outcome, treatment)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:3] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "counts" "outcome" "treatment"
      .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "outcome" "treatment" "outcome:treatment"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:3] "outcome" "treatment" "outcome:treatment"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:3] 1 1 2
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(counts, outcome, treatment)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:3] "numeric" "factor" "factor"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "counts" "outcome" "treatment"
  ..$ data             :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
      ..$ offset           : NULL
  ..$ control          :List of 3
      .. ..$ epsilon: num 1e-08
  .. ..$ maxit  : num 25
      .. ..$ trace  : logi FALSE
  ..$ method           : chr "glm.fit"
      ..$ contrasts        :List of 2
  .. ..$ outcome  : chr "contr.treatment"
      .. ..$ treatment: chr "contr.treatment"
  ..$ xlevels          :List of 2
      .. ..$ outcome  : chr  "1" "2" "3"
  .. ..$ treatment: chr  "1" "2" "3"
      ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "glm" "lm"
     - attr(*, "global.call")= language glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment + outcome * treatment, family = poisson())
     - attr(*, "terms")= atomic  (Intercept) outcome treatment outcome:treatment
      ..- attr(*, "interceptLabel")= chr "(Intercept)"
     - attr(*, "rank")=function (x)  
      ..- attr(*, "call")= language AICc(x)
      ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "function" "ICWithCall"
     - attr(*, "rank.call")= language AICc(x)
     - attr(*, "beta")= logi FALSE
     - attr(*, "call")= language dredge(global.model = glm.D93)
     - attr(*, "coefTables")=List of 5
      ..$ : coefTable [1:9, 1:3] 2.8904 -0.0572 -0.1823 0.1054 0.3285 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "(Intercept)" "outcome2" "outcome3" "treatment2" ...
      .. .. ..$ : chr  "Estimate" "Std. Error" "df"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "coefTable" "matrix"
  ..$ : coefTable [1, 1:3] 2.8134 0.0816 8
      .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "Estimate" "Std. Error" "df"
      .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "coefTable" "matrix"
      ..$ : coefTable [1:3, 1:3] 3.045 -0.454 -0.293 0.126 0.202 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "(Intercept)" "outcome2" "outcome3"
      .. .. ..$ : chr  "Estimate" "Std. Error" "df"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "coefTable" "matrix"
  ..$ : coefTable [1:3, 1:3] 2.81 8.93e-14 1.01e-12 1.41e-01 2.00e-01 ...
      .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. .. ..$ : chr  "(Intercept)" "treatment2" "treatment3"
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "Estimate" "Std. Error" "df"
      .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "coefTable" "matrix"
      ..$ : coefTable [1:5, 1:3] 3.04 -4.54e-01 -2.93e-01 8.72e-16 4.56e-16 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr  "(Intercept)" "outcome2" "outcome3" "treatment2" ...
      .. .. ..$ : chr  "Estimate" "Std. Error" "df"
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "coefTable" "matrix"
 - attr(*, "nobs")= int 9
>
```